# Dynamically assign a value of a dict with specific depth to the key of another dict with different depth

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

I am working with `requests` and I have some endpoints/services, their headers and their bodies. The bodies are dictionaries.

What I need to do is assign the value of a key from the response of one request to the body of another request, as it depends on some value returned from another request.

Let's assume the following two dictionaries:

```
d1 = {    # Dictionary that has to be updated
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "c": 2,
        "d": {
            "e": 3,
            "f": 4
        }
    }
    }

d2 = {    # Dictionary from which we need a certain value to assign to the other dict
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "c": 2,
        "d": {
            "e": 3,
            "f": 4
        },
        "x": 100
    }
    }
```

In this example, I need to assign the value of `"f"` from `d2` to the key `"c"` from `d1`.

Of course, this can be easily achieved by reassigning the values manually as such:

```
d1["b"]["c"] = d2["b"]["d"]["f"]
```

However, what I want is to be able to do this more flexibly, without using the expression above because the depth of each dictionary is not always the same and the key that I need may be on different levels for different requests.

I want to be able to pass the key hierarchy for the element I need for both dictionaries as a string, and let a function take care of the rest dynamically.

Something like this:

```
def depends_on(to_change, to_retrieve):
    # the logic

depends_on("b, c", "b, d, f") # This should assign the value of "f" to the value of "c"
```

Is it possible to achieve this? I couldn't find a way to dynamically generate a varying number of dictionary selectors.

Comment: but variant with external function is even more code, why do you need this?

Comment: because as I said, the key depth is not always the same and I cannot assign the key from the response to the body of the other request immediately after because the endpoints are some complex classes in my program and they are fired randomly. What I need is to create some kind of "rule" that once a request that needs something from another is fired, it will look at the last response of the other request, which is always available to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on the problem (recursion):

```
d1 = {    
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "c": 2,
        "d": {
            "e": 3,
            "f": 4
        }
    }
    }

d2 = {    
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "c": 2,
        "d": {
            "e": 3,
            "f": 4
        },
        "x": 100
    }
}

def find_key(key, d, to_change=None):
    current_key = key[0]

    if current_key in d:
        if not key[1:]:
            if to_change:
                d[current_key] = to_change
            return d[current_key]

        return find_key(key[1:], d[current_key], to_change=to_change)

def depends_on(v1, v2, d1, d2):
    k1 = find_key(v1, d1)
    find_key(v2, d2, to_change=k1)

depends_on(('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd', 'f'), d1, d2)
print(d2)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': {'e': 3, 'f': 2}, 'x': 100}}
```

Function `depends_on(v1, v2, d1, d2)`:

```
v1 => key from dict d1 
v2 => key from dict d2 
d1 => dict that the value is from 
d2 => dict that needs to be updated
```